# All database dispeared when i set hide_db in config.inc.php of phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpmyadmin - xampp on mac OS,
and I was afraid of distroying one of the system database of phpmyadmin so i wrote :

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = 'information_schema|performance_schema|phpmyadmin|mysql';
```

But after i saved the file and go to the browser and refresh all the databases have been disappeared

This image of the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out the line you added to confirm it's the culprit. Once confirmed, try this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = 'information_schema|performance_schema|mysql';
```

Comment: When i coomented out the line the databases appears again but when i add the new line it disappeared

Comment: Ok, do not put information_schema and performance_schema on this line; anyway those are not real databases.